# Different response from different browser

Tags: wordpress

I have a JSON API Add-on.

There is a query for getting the result stored in the database but it gives a different response in the different systems.

I already cleared the browser cookies and cache but nothing happens.
It stores device id again and again even it already store

My function is as follow:

```
public function store_device_id()
{
  global $wpdb;
  $device_id = $_REQUEST['device_id'];
  $device_type = $_REQUEST['device_type'];
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'ws_details';
  if(!empty($device_id) && !empty($device_type)) :
    $check = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT * FROM $table_name WHERE device_id like '%".$device_id."%'" );
    if($check == '')
    {
        $result = $wpdb->insert( $table_name,array( 
                'time' => current_time( 'mysql' ), 
                'device_id' => $device_id,
                'device_type' => $device_type ), 
            array( '%s', '%s', '%s'));
        if ($result) 
        {
            $res = 'Device id saved.';
        } else {
            $res = 'Device id did not save.';
        }
    }
    else{
        $res = 'Device already register.';
    }
else :
    $res = 'Please enter device id & device type.';
endif;

nocache_headers();
$post = new JSON_API_Post();
$post = $res;
return array(
      'post' => $post
    );
}
```

Here you have the **Table** structure:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_ws_details` (
>     `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>     `device_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
>     `device_type` varchar(55) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
>     `time` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
>     UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

Comment: where are you using this api?

Comment: i'm using this api for the webservice in android

Comment: In this where clause is not working for searching the device id,
so i change the login but this is temporary ,i need a solution 

please help me....

Comment: why you stored device_id and device_type in different table?
You can store as user_meta.

Comment: take a look http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/189077/how-to-get-users-by-a-custom-field-by-user-meta-data
you can obtain user detail by meta key

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting different responses from different browsers, then there is most definitely a caching issue and it's client side. Try your function without calling `nocache_headers()` and see what kind of results you get.